# Sentence segmentation dataset

Tags: data-request, nlp, corpora

I am looking for datasets that contain texts as well as notations for sentence boundaries. I plan to use it to assess a sentence segmentation system. I am mostly interested in texts in English at the moment, but curious about other languages as well.

Answer (score 3):

The [Pragmatic Segmenter](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter) segmentation library contains sentences for the common edge cases in English as well as some other languages. The README also includes links to a lot of research and other segmentation libraries.

You can also access the Brown Corpus from the [NLTK Corpora](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) page. That dataset has been used to test segmentation libraries.

Comment: 51 English edge cases from Pragmatic Segmenter: https://s3.amazonaws.com/tm-town-nlp-resources/golden_rules.txt